# AWS .NET Microservice Extractor tool fails with exception "Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed"

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

I'm following [this document](https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/c8d702fa-5eb6-4b3e-98a6-539b1785cec0/en-US/1-prerequisites) to review the AWS .NET Microservices Extrator.
I created profile. The profile has the security credential with access to permission as outlined on [this doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/microservice-extractor/latest/userguide/user-guide.pdf). Basially, I created the policy, attached the policy to my user and then created security credentials. The credential (access key ID and the secret) are used creating a profile in the AWS Microservice Extractor tool.

However, upon doing all that, the onboaring is not working.
The log files basically says:

{"id":"778dfa72-2973-4d44-b7d4-68523ed23e07","task":"UpdateMetricsProfileTask","parameters":[{"parameter":"Profile","values":[""]},{"parameter":"SendMetrics","values":["false"]},{"parameter":"UseDefaultCredentials","values":["false"]}]}
[2022-08-22 14:11:12.816] [error] **Failed sending AWS profile to analysis server Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed**

at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:399:19)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
at analysisServerCommonLogic (C:\Users\p124f32\AppData\Local\Programs\AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET\resources\app.asar\ts-dist\components\analysisServerOrchestrator\analysisServerCommunication.js:202:43)
at updateMetricsProfileTask (C:\Users\p124f32\AppData\Local\Programs\AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET\resources\app.asar\ts-dist\components\analysisServerOrchestrator\analysisServerCommunication.js:164:47)
at C:\Users\p124f32\AppData\Local\Programs\AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET\resources\app.asar\ts-dist\components\engine\engineSetting.js:99:88
at C:\Users\p124f32\AppData\Local\Programs\AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET\resources\app.asar\ts-dist\components\dataHandler\getConfig\getConfig.js:23:17
at newArguments. (C:\Users\p124f32\AppData\Local\Programs\AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET\resources\app.asar\node_modules\nedb\lib\executor.js:29:17)
at Cursor.execFn (C:\Users\p124f32\AppData\Local\Programs\AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET\resources\app.asar\node_modules\nedb\lib\datastore.js:484:12)
at callback (C:\Users\p124f32\AppData\Local\Programs\AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET\resources\app.asar\node_modules\nedb\lib\cursor.js:126:19)

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for using AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET.

We understand that you are having issues onboarding an application with AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET. We would like to let you know that today we released version 1.5.2, which addresses several known issues.

To update to the latest version of AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET, you can either:

1. Close and reopen the tool. On the pop-up window, click Restart; OR
2. Download and install the latest [installer](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/aws.serviceextract.download/latest/windows/ServiceExtract.exe) directly

Please let us know if this does not solve your problem or if you have any more questions. We would be happy to setup a conference call to help you.

Kind regards, AWS Microservice Extractor for .NET Team